# Send BrokeredMessage from Postman to Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, postman, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Function that is triggerd from Azure Service Bus. I want to test it locally and call my running Azure Function from Postman as it is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http

It seems that I manage to call my local Azure Function from Postman because I get 202 Accepted response. But in the console there is error when I make the call:

```
A ScriptHost error has occurred
Exception while executing function: Functions.MyAzFunction. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myBrokeredMessage'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Unable to convert trigger to BrokeredMessage.
```

It doesn't even stop to very first row when I try to debug:

```
public static async Task Process(BrokeredMessage myBrokeredMessage, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
  var foo = "bar";
  // real code...
}
```

What should I put as the body of the http request to get even to that very first row? Or something else?

Comment: Which version you are using, v1 or v2? The Azure Functions v2 doesn't use BrokeredMessage any more.

Comment: It is version 1.

Answer (score 2):

Although not quite following the article you mentioned, I think it's easiest to test your Function using the [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) to send message to the queue your Function is listening on.

> The Service Bus Explorer allows users to connect to a Service Bus namespace and administer messaging entities in an easy manner. The tool provides advanced features like import/export functionality or the ability to test topic, queues, subscriptions, relay services, notification hubs and events hubs.

[image: Service Bus Explorer]

Comment: This looks interesting, I will try it. But my aim is to automate my tests and seems like a manual testing tool.

Comment: Automated tests should, IMHO, test the functionality you implemented. Therefore I wouldn't expect it to test the Functions infrastructure of triggering based on a message in a queue. Test the logic (_your_ logic) of _processing_ that message. And by separating that out in your implementation, you should be able to test it pretty easily.

Comment: Yes, this must be an answer from automation perspective as well.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. My problem is that there isn't any unit tests and current code is impossible to unit test. So I would like to have first few integration test before I can refactor the code and write unit tests. And for that integration test it would help if I can call the Azure Function via REST.

Answer (score 0):

Serialise the equivalent ServiceBus message payload as JSON and assign the JSON to the value of `input` (take care to escape the double quotes when putting the JSON payload as `input` field's value).

Say you pass a payload class in the ServiceBus message:

```
class Payload
{
  public string Foo {get;set;}
  public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

Then use the following as the raw request body in Postman:

```
{
  "input": "{ 
    \"Foo\": \"test\",
    \"Bar\": \"data\"
  }"
}
```

I found out the above through experimentation (the message text in Service Bus Explorer was JSON). Later found this [post](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20971#issuecomment-448971624) which also confirms this approach - the poster references the [source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Controllers/FunctionsController.cs#L98) which extracts the `input` and passes it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is an Insomnia plugin that uses the request hook to modify the message prior to sending.  AFAIK, Postman does not let you do a similar thing with pre-scripts (unless using variables) - [You cannot modify the request body using pre-scripts](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4808)

To resolve the issue for me, I created a plugin [re-format json body message as a BrokeredMessage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/insomnia-plugin-brokeredmessage) that does exactly as camios describes above.

As long as the additional header and body exist, it takes the stringified json data and wraps it in a new object:

```
const brokerMessage = {"input": body.text}; // wrap the message as a brokeredMessage payload
body.text = JSON.stringify(brokerMessage)   // update the request body with the fmt
context.request.setBody(body);
```

For a given message you might want to send:

```
{"eventType":1,"statusType":2,"id":177638636663,"name":"container-ue-1"}
```

The message posted becomes:

```
{"input": "{\"eventType\":1,\"statusType\":2,"id\":177638636663,"name\":\"container-ue-1\"}"}
```

Simply add the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/insomnia-plugin-brokeredmessage) to Insomnia (and enable it), then add a header `Brokered-Message` = true to any posts you'd like modified through this plugin.

[image]

This works great for testing any local functions, triggering non-http functions.